# How to send large image consistently over http using .Net HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, https, system.net.httpwebrequest

How to send large image consistently over HTTP using the .Net `HttpWebRequest`?

My code works when I send any image with a size below 50KB, but when the image size is greater than 100KB, I get the below error:

> The underlying connection was closed:
>   An unexpected error occurred on a receive..

Comment: What code do you use to send the image?

Comment: And could you also describe your environment? What is on the other side (where you send an image)?

Comment: Application is C# based and other side is IIS hosted web service application.
Yes, we have tried increasing below param to high values but still seeing error,
executionTimeout="300"
maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"
maxStringContentLength="8388608"